# Can I send a zip file that is imported using input type and get the same zip in python?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I wanted to get the zip file in Python. I tried the following.

```
    receive :function (event) {
        var zipFile = new JSZip()
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            zipFile.loadAsync(file).then(function(content) {
                return content.files["test.pdf"].async('text');
            }).then(function (txt) {
                 var user = session.uid;
                rpc.query({
                    model: 'account.invoice',
                    method: 'create',
                    args: [user,txt],
                    }).then(function (e) {
                        location.reload();
                    });
            });


    },
```

this is work on the change event on change of the input file. Here I am able to get the text inside the XML and can send it to python. But What if I have multiple files in the zip. If I am able to send the zip directly and can use the zip operation in python that would be perfect.

Thanks,
Lot of help is appreciated

Comment: You can check database restore process of odoo where they are accepting zip file for restoring database.

Comment: If you want to create a zip of multiple files, you could load all the data in IO buffer, then with ZipFile you could write all data as bytes, convert this into base64 and load it to attachments, in the end, return the attachment downloader action.